# "Давайте будем на ты" - a useful sentence?

Tags: словоупотребление

I am reading now a book about Russian language (The big silver book of Russian language p. 2) and it's written there that when people want to talk to new people then they should say the sentence: "Давайте будем на ты". I've never came across it. Is it indeed done?

> **ты** is  the  informal  usage  for  you.  It  is  used  with  family 
>   members,  children,  close friends,  and  pets.  When  Russians  wish 
>   to  speak  informally  to  one  another  for  the first time, they
>   say, “ **Давайте будем на ты**  .”
>
> The  Russian  has  two  forms  for  you.  They  vary  according  to 
>   formality  and  number.Тыis informal singular, **вы** is formal singular
>   and both formal and informal plural. **Вы** is the marker of formality,
>   politeness, and seniority. Whenever you are in doubtabout  which  form
>   to  use,  err  on  the  side  of  caution  and  use  the  polite  form
>   (**Вы**) unless you are speaking to a child or a pet.

Comment: in some communities or contexts though "вы" might be considered cold, stressing official non-cohesive communication style, stressing the distance between talking parties.

Comment: btw, in English there still is ты  pronoun - thou. While almost never used in spoken language, but you may for example read Shakespeare, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, absolutely.

I would not suggest to say "`*давай* будем на ты`", because this seems rude to me. You start to call your vis-a-vis "ты" before she/he gave her/his consent.

Another common expression is `предлагаю перейти на ты`. This expression avoids using either ты or вы.

Comment: "Давай на ты" is correct spoken form when you invite your [younger] buddy to not call you "вы", while you're already using "ты" (and thus "давай" without "-те").

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.** "Давайте будем на ты", is a well known and standard phrase. You can also say "давай будем на ты" to emphasize the fact that you are very inclined to be less formal.

The other standard forms are: "Давай[те]/Может [сразу]/[перейдём] на ты?" or "можно на ты [сразу]/[уже]?"

It's worth to know also the verb "тыкать". It's a colloquial term for referring someone by "ты". You can here something like "Ничего, что я тыкаю? Мы ж всего день знакомы". The verb "тыкать" has homonym which translated as "to poke" and should not be confused with.

Comment: "давай будем на ты" is already addressing in singular. It is about like throw yourself onto someone's bed and then after what you already did ask for permission to sit there. Risky course of actions.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the already posted answers, I'd like to point out that the statement that

> when people want to talk to new people then they should say the sentence ...

is not exactly true. It sounds as if your book suggests that *whenever* people talk to new people, they *should* say this sentence — but that isn't so. You can never ever say this when you've just met new people and started talking to them, because that would be rude. It's only appropriate when you've been communicating at least for some time, and you feel that you and your vis-à-vis have established a certain rapport that allows for less formal relationship.

Comment: This deserves more upvotes since it actually may be rude to say to new people, especially under (semi-)formal circumstances.